# authenticate a user in jsf 2.0

Tags: jsf, javabeans

I am about developing a web application using jsf 2.0 and netbeans 7.1
so I want to authenticate users before they can access the application

My question know is how can I be sure of that user along his "session"?

I searched  and found that I have to use session beans but I didn't get 
the "remedy" of my problem

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer really depends on your requirements.  the simplest solution would be to use container managed authentication (via JAAS).  all j2ee/servlet containers support this, but some implement it "their own way", so you have to check the docs.  i know for tomcat and jboss, it's very simple to turn on and (assuming you configure your web.xml properly) just trust that if they are loading your pages, the session is authorized.  you might want to bulk up the question with some of your requirements.  that will really spur people to give you a much more concrete answer than i'm providing.

TIA